# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returning nil

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I have the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    /*2010-11-02 20:31:39*/
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"2010-11-02 20:31:39"];
```

`date` is `nil`.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 21):

The `hh` symbol is used for hours between 1 and 12. Use `HH` for hours between 1 and 24. Also, `YYYY` is used for the week-numbering year. You probably want `yyyy` instead.

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Check out [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for details.

Comment: [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateTxt]; not working where dateTxt = 2013-04-03 15:39:54

Comment: yes James is Correct,    "yyyy" is used for representing years in a date and "YYYY" is used for getting the week number for the particular data